# Laravel develop Blade template Engine

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

i want to use custom code in blade template engine such as custom function for use into that

my function:

```
public function viewCurrentDate( $arg=0 ){
     return 'date is'.date('y');
}
```

in Blade template use like with this code

```
@< viewCurrentDate >@
```

how to develop blade for custom actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in the filters.php file

```
Blade::extend(function ($view) {
   return str_replace("@dateY", 'date is'.date('y'), $view);
});
```

in template :

```
<h1>@dateY</h1>
```

Full tutorial about blade extension here : http://blog.zerilliworks.net/blog/2013/04/03/blade-extensions-in-laravel/

Comment: +1 hadn't realised that this could be done in laraval. New to L4?

Comment: i'm not sure if its new in L4, i have not reviewed the L3 docs

Comment: after a brief google search, seems to be that the feature is already present on 3.x laravel versions

Comment: If it has a facade and is invokable inside the `Blade::extend` function yes

Comment: its going to get messy if you do it like that. Everything is going to be tightly coupled together. What happens if you modify your model or controller? You will have to go through and update all your extended blade strings

Answer (score 1):

This is possible (see markcial's answer) but I think there is a much better way to do it.

Why not just set up a HTML helper class.

```
class HTMLHelper {

   public static function viewCurrentDate($arg = 0){
     return 'date is'.date('y');
   }

}
```

You can then add this to echo the date in your blade file:

```
{{ HTMLHelper::viewCurrentDate() }}
```

It is slightly more characters (compared to what you wanted), but will be so much more flexible for you as you can add as many helper methods to your class as you like and use them anywhere, not just in blade.

Edit: Whilst markcial's answer is what you are after (tells you how to create a new template string in blade) I'd don't think that is the simplest way to do things. The helper file is much more flexible and reusable. For example, you can use this helper file ANYWHERE in your app. With markcial's answer, you are only allowing blade to use what you have written. To me, it doesn't seem worth it when a more flexible, easier solutions is available.

Comment: @gaz-edge witch file must be append this class?

Comment: @TuxWorld - i dont understand. Are you asking what this class is and where  it lives? You will have to create this class yourself. Id put it in the libraries folder, but you can put it wherever you want. You may also want to call it HTMLHelper just so its clear

Comment: i'm create `HTMLHelper` in root of laravel and into that i have `HTMLHelper.php`. i'm pasting your class into that. how to call it now?

Comment: id try putting it in your models folder initially. You can then call it as Ive written it (to see if you like using it) as i think laravel auto loads the model folder for you, so no need for namespaces etc

Comment: why i can not use any name for class such as MyHTMLHelper ?

Comment: erm, you can. You are defining your class, use what ever you want.

Comment: sigh... this is VERY basic stuff. I suggest you google. But first, make sure the file is in your model folder. Make sure the file name and class name match

Comment: better way? well... if you think so... IMHO is not better than the laravel proposed way

Comment: @markcial 'not better than the laravel proposed way'. So just because laravel allows it, it MUST be the best way? Very interesting view to have, but you are entitled to it.

Comment: creating a class instead using a compiled closure? that is so php4. Again use whatever you want to, but i do not think that everything need to be a class

Comment: writing code to only be used in one area of an app? That is so procedural.

Comment: is used in every place of the template you use that tag, doing an extra class for that is adding extra noise and extra memory consumption. If you want to make that a class BTW you can use facades inside the extend function anyways and what i am telling to do is not basic is pythonic, is using a lambda inside a closure list waiting for execution ;)